# Will calling a progress report method slow down a C# file download on Windows Phone 7 significantly?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient

I have a Windows Phone 7 (7.1) method in C# that given a URL in string form downloads the contents of that URL to a file (see code below).  As you can see from the code, I assign a *DownloadProgressChanged()* event handler.  In that handler, if the caller provided an **IProgress** object, I call the *Report()* method on that object.  Given the potential for the user having a slow Web connection, I want to make sure that the download will go as fast as possible.  Will calling the *IProgress.Report()* method in the **WebClient's** *DownloadProgressChanged()* callback slow down the download considerably?

I'm not familiar enough with *IProgress.Report()* to know if it executes on the current thread or the calling thread.  Does it execute on the calling thread?  My concern is that a repetitive thread switch would really bog things down.  I'll probably wrap the call to this method in a *Task.Run()* call to keep the UI thread happy.  But just in case, I'll ask if there any potential problems with my code as far as bogging down the UI thread is concerned?

Any other comments on the code pertaining to structure or performance are appreciated.  Note, I'm using the **Microsoft.Bcl.Async** package in this app.

**UPDATE (added later)**:  In regards to thread switching, apparently the DownloadProgressChanged() event is raised on the UI thread, not the download thread, so there is no need to do anything fancy with Dispatcher or the like to do UI updates in this scenario.  At least according to this Code Project article:

[Progress Reporting in C# 5 Async](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129447/Progress-Reporting-in-C-5-Async)

```
    public static void URLToFile(string strUrl, string strDestFilename, IProgress<int> progress, int iNumSecondsToWait = 30)
    {
        strUrl = strUrl.Trim();

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strUrl))
            throw new ArgumentException("(Misc::URLToFile) The URL is empty.");

        strDestFilename = strDestFilename.Trim();

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strDestFilename))
            throw new ArgumentException("(Misc::URLToFile) The destination file name is empty.");

        if (iNumSecondsToWait < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("(Misc::URLToFile) The number of seconds to wait is less than 1.");

        // Create the isolated storage file.
        StreamWriter sw = openIsoStorFileAsStreamWriter(strDestFilename);

        // If the stream writer is NULL, then the file could not be created.
        if (sw == null)
            throw new System.IO.IOException("(Misc::URLToFile) Error creating or writing to the file named: " + strDestFilename);

        // Asynchronous download.  Note, the Silverlight version of WebClient does *not* implement 
        //  IDisposable.
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            // Create a download progress changed handler so we can pass on progress
            //  reports to the caller if they provided a progress report object.
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Do we have a progress report handler?
                if (progress != null)
                    // Yes, call it.
                    progress.Report(e.ProgressPercentage);
            };

            // Use a Lambda expression for the "completed" handler
            //  that writes the contents to a file.
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
                e.Result.CopyTo(sw.BaseStream);

            // Now make the call to download the file.
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(strUrl));
        }
        finally
        {
            // Make sure the stream is cleaned up.
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();

            // Make sure the StreamWriter is diposed of.
            sw.Dispose();
        } // try/finally

        // CancellationTokenSource srcCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        // srcCancelToken.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iNumSecondsToWait));
    } // public static void URLToFile()
```

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the download progress check does not necessarily affect the download speed. Mainly because the items that are checked are not downloaded per-se. When you initiate the download, you get a size declaration (content length) - that is used as a reference for a complete file. Then, the size of the local (downloaded) byte content is checked and a ratio can be built from the two values.

**NOTE:** Does not apply for streaming, for obvious reasons, since there is no final size estimate.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if a call to IProgress.Report() occurs on the calling thread, or the thread that created the IProgress object?

Comment: WebClient downloads and the related progress reporting are done on the UI thread.